# windows 7 internet speed significantly slower than ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

i have windows 7 x64 and ubuntu 10.04 installed on my machine. while i download at ~15 MiB/sec in ubuntu (reaches almost at an instant), it takes almost a minute or two for win7 to reach that speed while downloading -say- a film. also the connection becomes unresponsive for some time periods in win7. i experienced this in several win7 installations (x64 prof. always, same version).

Comment: Different machines? Malware-Scanner?

Answer (score 4):

The slowdown might be due to [TCP window scale option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option).

The article [Receive Window Auto-Tuning on Vista](https://web.archive.org/web/20200609225520/https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wndp/receive-window-auto-tuning-on-vista) says the following:

> If your connection from a Vista
> machine appears slow or hung, here are
> some steps to isolate the cause:
>
> - First, make sure that your firewall and router can support window scaling.
>   You can check with the manufacturer or
>   run the connectivity diagnostic suite
>   (especially, TCP High Performance
>   Test) provided by Microsoft to
>   determine your gateway device’s
>   compliance.
> - Second, check with the manufacturer if a firmware update has been issued
>   for your device that can fix the
>   problem.
> - Third, If the problem still persists, you can restrict autotuning
>   by running “netsh interface tcp set
>   global autotuninglevel=restricted”
>   from the command prompt. We have found
>   that restricted mode will often allow
>   some of the benefits of autotuning
>   with a number of problematic devices.
> - Lastly, if all else fails, in order to disable this feature, run "netsh
>   interface tcp set global
>   autotuninglevel=disabled".
> - (In order to reenable autotuning, run “netsh interface tcp set global
>   autotuninglevel=normal”.)

Comment: Had to go through these exact steps when I upgraded and found out my router was a wee bit old.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and used [Dr. TCP](http://www.dslreports.com/drtcp) to adjust registry settings. It worked very well and brought me up to the DSL speeds my phone company said I should be getting.

Comment: What settings do you recommend to use?

Comment: It's been awhile, but I think I just selected my wireless network card clicked **Apply** and rebooted.

Comment: so you basically kept the default values?

Comment: Sorry I can't say definitely because I just don't remember, but I believe you are correct, I just used the default values and after applying restarted my computer.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the same browser?

Firefox which is ubuntu's default browser is a lot faster than windows default Internet Explorer.

If you are using same browser then it might be down to the way each operating system handles the internet.

Comment: yes i do use the same browser both on ubuntu and win 7: google chrome.